# Dependency version in maven pom.xml

Tags: maven-3, pom.xml

I came across a maven pom.xml where properties were used to state dependency versions.

There was this property

```
<aerospike.version>[3.0.0,)</aerospike.version>
```

Can somebody explain how to comprehend this ?

Comment: Link http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Version_Requirement_Specification explains dependency version. For the dependency you listed it's any version >= 3.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The range `[3.0.0,)` means a version which is greater than or equal to `3.0.0`.

Using

```
<aerospike.version>[3.0.0,)</aerospike.version>
```

means Maven will enforce that the version it uses is at least `3.0.0` or higher for this depedency.

Here is a [link to the documentation](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html) for Maven version ranges.

Comment: so, does this means if a new version is made available it will be downloaded and used automatically when the project is build?

Comment: I believe this means that Maven will insist on using a version `3.0.0` or higher, but it will try to get the latest version available.  Once you have a satisfactory version in your `.m2` folder, it won't automatically update unless you force it to.

Comment: Added note: If your build setup always tries to update then Maven _will_ try to get the latest version.